# Whether the element of an integer pointer array can pointer to an integer array?

Tags: c++

I am wondering the ptr[i] pointer in the following code can be pointed to an integer array, why or why not. The problem is that if there exists another integer array (i.e. int brr[] = {4,5,6}), whether ptr[i] can be pointed to the integer array (i.e. brr)or it can just point to an integer(i.e. brr[i]), why or why not?

```
#include <stdio.h> 

const int SIZE = 3; 

void main() 
{ 

    // creating an array 
    int arr[] = { 1, 2, 3 }; 

    // we can make an integer pointer array to 
    // storing the address of array elements 
    int i, *ptr[SIZE]; 

    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) { 

        // assigning the address of integer. 
        ptr[i] = &arr[i]; 
    } 

    // printing values using pointer 
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) { 

        printf("Value of arr[%d] = %d\n", i, *ptr[i]); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: What language are you really programming in? Please tag only that language, and no other.

Comment: A pointer to an object can equally well be a pointer to the first element of an array of objects. Your code needs to keep track of that somehow.

Comment: And can you please elaborate on your doubts or thoughts? Why do you think the code you show is valid or invalid? And please take some time to refresh [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: And perhaps helping you understand some things: When required, all arrays will decay to a pointer to its first element. This happens rather frequently, including when using array indexing. For any array *or pointer* `arr` and index `i`, the expression `arr[i]` is exactly equal to `*(arr + i)`. And in the expression `*(arr + i)`, the sub-expression `arr` is represented by such a decayed pointer (so it's really `*(&arr[0] + i)`).

Answer (score 1):

An array decays to a pointer to its first element when used as an r-value. So

```
ptr[i] = arr;
```

is equivalent to

```
ptr[i] = &arr[0];
```

Since you already know that the latter is valid, so is the former.

Comment: Exactly, thanks a lot. However, what really confuses me is that ptr is an element of integer array, thus every element of the array can be a pointer. What I really want to know is that the element of the array can only point to an integer or it can be pointed  to to another integer array.

Comment: It can only point to an integer. The elements of the integer array are integers, so it can point to them.

Comment: When you write `ptr[i] = arr;`, it's not pointing to the array, it's pointing to the first element of the array.

Comment: To point to the array you would write `ptr[i] = &arr;`, but that's not valid.

Comment: why the element of  integer pointer array  can only point to an integer, why not an integer array

Comment: @amont Regarding pointing to the array itself (`&arr)` you can't use an `int *` type for that.  A pointer to a single element (like a pointer to its first element, which is what you get with `&arr[0]` or plain `arr`) is of the correct type (`int *`). But a pointer to the array itself, using `&arr`, is of the type `int (*)[3]`. This is semantically very different.

Comment: @amont The same reason that an integer pointer can't point to a float. An integer pointer can only point to an integer.

Comment: @Barmar thanks, I suddenly understand how two-dimensional array works.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude There is one more question is how to understand the case "int *ptr = new int[3]", the ptr point to an integer array. Thanks.

Comment: @amont No, the `new int[3]` expression will return a pointer to the first element of the allocated memory. After `int* ptr = new int[3]` then `ptr == &ptr[0]` is true.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude then what is the exactly difference of pointer to the first element of an array and point to an array(like int(*)[3])

Comment: @amont You mean besides the incompatible types? I though that would be enough.

Comment: An array decays to a pointer to its first element. But that also works in reverse. Say you have `int *p = &arr[1];`. Then the following is valid: `p[-1] + p[0] + p[1]`. There is no such thing as a pointer to just one int where the compiler doesn't allow pointer arithmetic or indexing with []. It's the programmers job to make sure you know what pointers point at and behave correctly.